# javascript $find returns null in IE

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using the AJAX Control Toolkit control "TextBoxWaterMarkExtender". The problem originally was that in Firefox, setting the text with javascript like so:

```
var getDateField = document.getElementById('soandso');
getDateField.value = 'someandsome';
```

Would be cleared on submit/post because the Extender control thought that nobody had edited it, so it was clearing the "watermark".

I followed this workaround: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Workaround-for-TextBoxWatermarkExtender-of-AjaxControlToolkit--855.php

and it works great in Firefox, but IE says "'null' is null or not an object" on this line:

```
var dateIdentified = $find("Beh" + sender).get_Text();
```

Anything obvious that I'm missing?

Edit: Sorry guys, I thought $find was a jQuery function.

Edit: More code:

```
function dateToday(sender)
        {
            var dateIdentified = $find("Beh" + sender).get_Text();
            if (dateIdentified.length == 0)
            {
                var todaydate = new Date();
                var smonth = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
                var sday = todaydate.getDate();
                var syear = todaydate.getFullYear();
                $find("Beh" + sender).set_Text(smonth.toString() + '/' + sday.toString() + '/' + syear.toString());
            }
        }
```

WaterMark:

```
<toolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender BehaviorID="BehSTART_DATE" ID="WaterMarkSTART_DATE" runat="server"  
 TargetControlID="dcSTART_DATE"
 WaterMarkText="mm/dd/yyyy" WaterMarkCssClass="searchHint" />
```

Comment: First off, your initial example is native Javascript. In the second example, you aren't calling the .find() method correctly. What are you trying to do? http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: the $find command is from the .net javascript libraries. it isnt jQuery. it is used to find .net dom extensions like the `TextboxWaterMarkExtender` or `Accordion`.

Comment: can you provide more code around the line where you are getting the error? also, include the markup for the watermark extender

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this. What is the value that you are passing into `dateToday()`? Is it `'START_DATE'`?

Comment: @Jeff, yes that's not the problem. Remember, it works in Firefox and not in IE.

Comment: well, i was thinking that maybe it it was different capitalization (i.e. `'Start_Date'`) there might be some browser quirks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested to know, I switched from using body onLoad to call my javascript function to

```
Sys.Application.add_load(MyFunction);
```

as this article suggested: http://blogs.telerik.com/dimodimov/posts/08-12-13/don_t_use_body_onload_in_asp_net_ajax_websites.aspx

Now IE, Firefox and Chrome all see a value for the $find.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("Beh" + sender).text();
```

find() is used when you've already looked up an element or elements and you want to find child elements inside of them. For example, you grab a table and then want to find all elements inside the table with a class of foo, like so:

```
var myTable = $('#myTable');
// more code
myTable.find('.foo');
```

Comment: $("Beh" + sender).text();
Returns null as well.

Comment: I should note that this is for jQuery only. If you're using the MS ajax library, this code wouldn't work. It seems like the MS library has hijacked the $ so you might try substituting jQuery for the $ in my code (eg. jQuery("Beh" + sender); )

Comment: for some reason I can't even call it like that. jQuery is undefined. I have the src included though.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your javascript console? They might indicate why jQuery isn't getting loaded. Edit: Confirm your file path to jquery is correct too. A bad path has gotten me more than once.